# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes, Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I 'm using the latest version of umbraco (7.2) and I have a problem .

When compiling my solution have no compilation error but when I run I get [this error:](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img673/2739/HzkzVJ.png)

[image: here]

Already tried to install everything, including installing and uninstalling dll's and could not.

Someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I got that sort of same error a few days ago, noticed that on solution build there were a few Umbraco dlls that were removed somehow by the build process and that was one of them.

So far what i have done was replace the dlls from the download of Umbraco files and then add their references and so far seems ok not sure why they are deleted but i think its because the build process somehow treats them as not required.